# How to get the user's name from the Instagram API?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

The Instagram Basic Display API "allows you to get a user's profile" though is there a way to retrieve the Full Name of the user?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user

The link above shows that you can return the username but cannot get anything meaningful such as their Name, website or Bio - though you are able to get all of their media.

I believe it is possible with the Graph API (which is for professional accounts) but is there a way to do so with the Basic Display API?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to send a GET request to `https://instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1`. You'll find what you need inside `['graphql']['user']`